# Weird compiler error in MSVC

Tags: c, syntax, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying out the WinFUSE library and get a weird compiler error message.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fuse.h>

void* fuse_init(struct fuse_conn_info* conn) {
    printf("%s(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, conn);
    if (!conn) return NULL;
    conn->async_read = TRUE;
    conn->max_write = 128;
    conn->max_readahead = 128;
    return conn;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct fuse_operations ops = {0};

    // Fill the operations structure.
    ops.init = fuse_init;         // REFLINE 1

    void* user_data = NULL;       // REFLINE 2  (line 26, error line)
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &ops, NULL);
}
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\niklas\Desktop\test>cl main.c fuse.c /I. /nologo /link dokan.lib
main.c
main.c(26) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
fuse.c
Generating Code...
```

When I comment either *REFLINE 1* **or** *REFLINE 2*, compilation works fine.

#### 1: Works

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct fuse_operations ops = {0};

    // Fill the operations structure.
    // ops.init = fuse_init;         // REFLINE 1

    void* user_data = NULL;       // REFLINE 2
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &ops, NULL);
}
```

#### 2: Works

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct fuse_operations ops = {0};

    // Fill the operations structure.
    ops.init = fuse_init;         // REFLINE 1

    // void* user_data = NULL;       // REFLINE 2
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &ops, NULL);
}
```

### Question

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong? I'm compiling with

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60315.1 for x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft compilers support C89 only, and therefore do not permit the intermingling of declarations and code (this was added in C99). All variable declarations must be placed at the beginning of each block, before anything else. This would also work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct fuse_operations ops = {0};

    /* Fill the operations structure. */
    ops.init = fuse_init;

    {
        void* user_data = NULL;
    }

    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &ops, NULL);
}
```