# MEX missing ';' before type

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, mex

I'm trying to compile some code using MATLAB MEX and MSVS 2010 C compiler and getting this error. This code compiles well under Linux using gcc i guess. Any idea what is a reason ??

Krzysztof

```
205 plhs[0] = return_model;
206 plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
207 double *tt = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
208 *tt = model->obj;
209 plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
210 double *qq = mxGetPr(plhs[2]);
211 *qq = model->initial_time;
212 mxFree(rhs);
```

: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
C:\Users\Krzysztof\Desktop\doc\dcsvm\dcsvm_1.1\dcsvm_release\libsvm-3.14-nobias\matlab\svm_model_matlab.c(208)
: error C2065: 'tt' : undeclared identifier

Comment: If this is C code then you cannot mix declarations and code in C89, which is the C standard that MSVC supports. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779532/weird-compiler-error-in-msvc

Comment: Yes but the flag C99 is used during compilation   mex CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=c99" -largeArrayDims svmtrain.c ../svm.cpp svm_model_matlab.c

Comment: anyway i changed the extensions of files from .c to .cpp and managed to compile